# Radio box always displays undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an alert box which shows the value of radio box. The radio box always displays undefined. Why is it happening?

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script>    
          $("input[name='gender']").click(function(){
                var gender = $('#gender').val();
              //var url ="".cityname;
              alert(gender);
            //window.location.replace("search.php?gender="+gender);
        });

</script>
```

Comment: `#gender` doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess you want `var gender = $(this).val()` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
 $("input[name='gender']").click(function(){
                alert($(this).val());
            //window.location.replace("search.php?gender="+gender);
  });
```

You are looking for `this`, in your case you're selecting a div with an id of gender.